# SQL Server: How to calculate different sums in a single query

Tags: sql, t-sql

A friend has suggested I post here as I'm in need of a bit of help!

DB Layout:

```
**salestable**
salesorder [primary, unique] (sales order number)
salesman (salesperson id)

**salesline**
salesorder [many sales line to single salestable relationship]
saleprice (line amount)
isaccessory (0 or 1)
```

I'd like to, in a single select, sum sales price as a total per salesman, but also sum sales price where is accessory = 1.

The grouping and joins aren't what I'm stuck on, it's whether I can do the dual sum.

In my head it would look something like

```
...salesman,sum(amount) as totalsales,sum(amount where accessory=1) as accessorysales...
```

But obviously that would never work!

Thanks in advance! (PS, I'm very new here, be gentle...)

Comment: @Jon: I've removed the "Über" from the title. Many SQL problems discussed here have a lot more complexity than this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT  salesman, SUM(amount), SUM(CASE WHEN accessory = 1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END)
FROM    salestable t
JOIN    salesorder o
ON      o.salesorder = t.salesorder
GROUP BY
        salesman
```

Comment: You slippery fish! You beat me to it. +1

Comment: @Welbog: you didn't bind the keys, did you?

Comment: @Quassnoi: Rather I was caught up in an explanation of what the `CASE` statement is for... You just jump right into the SQL without explaining it.

Comment: @Welbog: in case of `CASE` (no pun intended), the query seems self-explanatory. Besides, as for me, forcing my way through documentation to find out how a program / query / whatever works has much more propaedeutic value than spoon-feed explanations. (This is of course when people ask for solutions, not for explanations).

Comment: Thank you people, you are all glorious.

@Quassnoi, you're right, I no longer need to think for myself (I'm joking!) Case is exactly what I was looking for, and while I'd usually dive into the manuals in this instance I don't have the time, or the mental capacity to do so.

Thanks again :)

Comment: @Quassnoi: What about  `SUM(amount * accessory)`? Works as long as `accessory` is always 0 or 1. Admittedly, it is a little bit sloppy.

Comment: @Tomalak - haha thanks. I thought that as I submitted! I'll come back with a real sql question some day.

Comment: @Jon: Sorry if it sounded rude, I didn't mean nothing like that :) I meant that *given a working program*, finding out how it works is of much more use (and fun) than reading the descriptions.

Comment: @Tomalak: will work if accessory is a `BIT`. However, this is sloppy indeed :)

Comment: @Quassnoi: Will work for `INT`, too. Preferably if there is a check constraint in place that limits the value. ;) The key question is - will it be faster?